# Is there a lightweight version of Tensorflow to load a model in production?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow model that I use to make predictions via API.
each time I want to make a prediction I end up loading the entire TensorFlow model with a size of about 1.0 GB that contains all of the functionality of analysis and training instead of loading a tiny function that does only one task which is loading my model.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model(
    "/tmp/current_model", 
    custom_objects=None,
    compile=True
)

predictions = model.predict(inputs, batch_size=1, verbose=1, steps=None, callbacks=None)
```

Is there a version or strategy to load a model & predict() that doesn't require the entire 1GB TensorFlow package? When not requiring any of the training functionality.

This issue is causing slow prediction times, and when doing multiprocessing it becomes even slower due to the package (about 1.0 GB) being loaded multiple times.

Comment: What you're looking for is [Model Optimization](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization).

Comment: @Innat I don't think this answers the question posed. The question isn't about running a pruned model, but about the package requirements for an application that just uses a trained ANN. Rather than `pip install tensorflow`, @GAEfan and myself would like to find some lightweight python package that can load the saved `.h5` model and perform a prediction.

Comment: I didn't give answer but comment with possible solutions. However, after seeing your comment, now I think the above quesitons is bit incomplete and need more details.